# Disable split view with supporting all orientations iOS

Tags: ios, swift, split, view

I want to prevent the application from being used split view, but support all orientations.
Everyone advises to set the parameter Requires full screen to true,
it prohibits the use spit view, but the application starts to support only one orientation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `NavigationView`:

```
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```